# keynote equations in latex : change to a sans-serif font

Tags: keynote, latex

I just realized that Keynote seem to now allow to type directly some latex (Insert > Equation).

I'd like to change the default font to a sans serif font (easier reading on a beamer).

More generally of course I'd be very happy to be able to write my own preamble for what's being compiled. Any chance someone would know how to do this ?